# Comparing multiple incidence rates of disease

Tags: statistical-significance, incidence-rate-ratio

I have a set of data of patients from different places who have had the same operation to remove their appendix. A small subset of the these patients have come back with cancer in the appendix. I calculated the incidence rate by dividing the total number of appendectomy/cancer of appendix and represented it as a percentage. I would like to compare the incidence rates of cancer of the appendix by state.

Sample data looks something like this

| State | Total number of appendectomy | Cancer in appendix | Incidence |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| State A | 500 | 25 | 5% |
| State B | 2000 | 20 | 1% |
| State C | 1000 | 5 | 0.5% |
| State D | 50 | 1 | 2% |
| State E | 5000 | 75 | 1.5% |
| All states | 8550 | 126 | 1.47% |

Is it possible for me to say that a state has a significantly higher or lower incidence rate than the other states? I want to suggest that by staying in a specific state places a patient at higher risk for cancer and maybe there's an environmental risk factor for this.

Or is there another way to represent the findings?

Thank you.

Comment: Your question has nothing to do with SPSS.  Please remove SPSS from the title.  Also, "statistical significance" means almost nothing so think about better tags related to comparisons in general, incidence, or normalization.

Comment: Thanks for the comments. I sorted that out as best as I can